# Python module overwrite double underscores

Tags: python, django

Does anyone know why my `__status__` string won't print? I get a `NameError`. Yet I can print CAT if I set it (It overrides).

So I cannot use the dual underscores because it's now a magic attribute to the module settings_local?

**settings.py**

```
__status__ = "Base"
CAT = 5
try:

    # This will work if a settings_local.py exists
    from settings_local import *

except ImportError as e:

    print "Add a settings_local blah blah"
    sys.exit()

print __status__ # returns Base
print CAT # Returns 1
print settings_local.__status__ # Returns NameError
```

**settings_local.py**

```
__status__ = "Development"
CAT = 1
```

Should I just do this in **settings_local.py**?

```
status = __status__
```

Then  just use it that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `from <module> import *` syntax *ignores* names starting with an underscore, if the target module has no `__all__` attribute (if it does only names listed in that attribute are imported). From the [`import` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> If the list of identifiers is replaced by a star (`'*'`), all public names defined in the module are bound in the local namespace of the `import` statement.
>
> The *public names* defined by a module are determined by checking the module’s namespace for a variable named `__all__`; if defined, it must be a sequence of strings which are names defined or imported by that module. The names given in `__all__` are all considered public and are required to exist. **If `__all__` is not defined, the set of public names includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin with an underscore character (`'_'`)**.

(*bold emphasis mine*).

Moreover, you did not import the `settings_local` module itself; the `NameError` is throws because you didn't import the module, only attributes contained in the module. This works:

```
import settings_local

print settings_local.__status__
```

Your other options would be:

- Two import statements:

  ```
  from settings_local import *
  try:
      from settings_local import __status__
  except ImportError:
      # no __status__ defined in the local settings
      pass
  ```
- Add an `__all__` list to your `settings_local.py` module:

  ```
  __all__ = ['CAT', '__status__']

  __status__ = "Development"
  CAT = 1
  ```

Note that [Python advises against creating new `__*__` names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> `Any` use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Comment: That makes sense, however I want to override all the CONSTANTS as well. should I use two import lines? `from settings_local import *` and `import settings_local`?

Comment: @JREAM: You can set an `__all__ = ['CAT', '__status__']` variable in the `settings_local` module to force `__status__` being imported.

Comment: @JREAM I don't know any django, but if `__status__` isn't something that it explicitly requires/expects, it might be worth noting that it is generally a [bad idea to create new `__*__` names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: Okay, Ill leave __status__ to the "authorship" block, and just pass a variable in, it seems more logical to do that way. I am trying to go by some PEP8 standards.